# Making a directory in QFileSystemModel using mkdir()

Tags: qt

I have made a simple program that show directory listing in QTreeView using QFileSystemModel.

With a QPushButton the program is calling a slot that is making a new directory, but it never makes a new directory.

This is the slot that makes a new directory:

```
QModelIndex index=viewTreeForModel->currentIndex();

if (!index.isValid()) return;

QString filename=QInputDialog::getText(this, "Enter Name Dialog", "Enter name");

modelFile->mkdir(viewTreeForModel->currentIndex(), filename);
```

I dont get a error messages from the program when it runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `QModelIndex` returned by mkdir is valid.

You could also try

```
const bool success = QDir(modelFile->filePath(index)).mkdir(string);
```

Then check the value of `success`.

As an aside, I would recommend renaming the variable `string` to something like `newfilename`, it would make the code more readable.

Comment: QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Acces denied
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /lost+found